# How do i use methods from a class that i made, when trying to use them in a SOP statement?

Tags: java, arrays

So im trying to use this code that i have to make for school:

```
public class QuizScore 
{
private int qs[];
EasyReader d = new EasyReader();
public QuizScore(int num)
{
    int qs[]=new int[num]; 
    for(int i=0;i<num;i++)
    {
     System.out.println("Enter in your scores: ");
     qs[i] = d.readInt();
    }
}
public int getMax()
{
    int max=0;
    if(qs.length==0)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    for(int i=0;i<qs.length;i++)
    {
        max=qs[i];
        if(qs[i+1]>qs[max])
        {
            max=qs[i+1];
        }
        else
        {
            max=qs[i];
        }
    }
    return max;
}
public int getMin()
{
    if(qs.length==0)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    int min=0;
    for(int i=0;i<qs.length;i++)
    {
        min=qs[i];
        if(qs[i+1]<qs[min])
        {
            min=qs[i+1];
        }
        else
        {
            min=qs[i];
        }
    }
    return min;
}
public double getAvg()
{
    if(qs.length==0)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    int total=0;
    for(int i=0;i>qs.length;i++)
    {
        total+=qs[i];
    }
    int avg = Math.round(total/qs.length*10)/10;
    return avg;
}
```

and with this code im trying to use them in these SOP statements.

```
public static void main(String args[])
{
    EasyReader d = new EasyReader();
    System.out.println("How many numbers are in your array?");
    int num = d.readInt();
    new QuizScore(num);
    System.out.println("Average: \t"+getAvg);
    System.out.println("Range: \t"+getMin+" - "+getMax);
    System.out.println("Score \t Frequency");
    System.out.println("------------------");

}
```

}

what am i doing wrong? i cant seem to figure out why i cant enter in the method.

much appreciated.

Comment: `QuizScore q = new QuizScore(num); System.out.println("Average: \t"+q.getAvg()); ...`  :)

Answer (score 1):

You are creating a new QuizeScore Object with the new Operator which returns the new Object, but you didnt save it in variable of type QuizScore. Do  `QuizScore variableName = new QuizScore(num);` and then you can access the methods of this object like: `variableName.getAvg()`;  And dont forget brackets when you call a method.

```
EasyReader d = new EasyReader();
System.out.println("How many numbers are in your array?");
int num = d.readInt();
QuizScore myQS = new QuizScore(num);
System.out.println("Average: \t"+myQS.getAvg());
System.out.println("Range: \t"+myQS.getMin()+" - "+myQS.getMax());
System.out.println("Score \t Frequency");
System.out.println("------------------");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class QuizScore 
{
private int qs[];                  // you are declaring array here
EasyReader d = new EasyReader();
public QuizScore(int num)
{
    int qs[]=new int[num];        // declaring new array and using it.. You are not using the qs declared earlier.. Its scope is local. Change it to qs = new int[num]; 

    for(int i=0;i<num;i++)
    {
     System.out.println("Enter in your scores: ");
     qs[i] = d.readInt();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use new keyword with non static methods , you can't directly use the class name with the methods.

```
public static void main(String args[])
{

EasyReader d = new EasyReader();
System.out.println("How many numbers are in your array?");
int num = d.readInt();
new QuizScore(num);
System.out.println("Average: \t"+new QuizScore(num).getAvg());
System.out.println("Range: \t"+new QuizScore(num).getMin()+" - "+new QuizScore(num).getMax());   
 System.out.println("Score \t Frequency");
System.out.println("------------------");

 }

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Once check your code, the code should be as follows. We can access the instance methods with the help of object only. So create object, assign the reference to a variable and access methods.

```
QuizScore qs = new QuizScore(num);
System.out.println("Average: \t"+qs.getAvg());
System.out.println("Range: \t"+qs.getMin()+" - "+qs.getMax());
System.out.println("Score \t Frequency");
System.out.println("------------------");
```

I guess it helps.